# Discord py give command error. I am making economy discord py bot, but give command doesn't work

Tags: python, discord, discord.py

```
import discord
from discord.ext import commands
import os
import json
import random
from discord.ext.commands import Bot


os.chdir("")
```

there is correct path, i checked this

```
Bot = commands.Bot(command_prefix = "$")

token = 'my token'
```

which is also correct

```
@Bot.command()
async def give(ctx, member:discord.Member, amount = None):
    await open_account(ctx.author)
    await open_account(member)

    amount = int(amount)
    if amount == None:
        await ctx.send("Please enter the amount")
        return

    bal = await update_bank(ctx.author)

    if amount>bal[1]:
        await ctx.send("You don't have that much money")
        return

    if amount<=0:
        await ctx.send("Amount must be positive")
        return

    await update_bank(ctx.author, -1*amount, "wallet")
    await update_bank(member, 1*amount, "wallet")

    emb = discord.Embed(description = f"You gave {member.name} {amount} gold coins", color = 0x2ecc71)
    await ctx.send(embed = emb)
```

There is whole give command

```
async def open_account(user):
    
    users = await get_bank_data()


    if str(user.id) in users:
        return False
    else:
        users[str(user.id)] = {}
        users[str(user.id)]["wallet"] = 0

    with open("mainbank.json", "w") as f:
        json.dump(users, f)

    return True


async def update_bank(user, change = 0, mode = "wallet"):
    users = await get_bank_data()

    users[str(user.id)][mode] += change

    with open("mainbank.json", "w") as f:
        json.dump(users, f)

    bal = [users[str(user.id)]["wallet"]]

    return bal
```

As you can see, there is give command, which doesn't work. I also know, that problem isn't with open_account function, but I am not sure about update_bank.

There is an error:

```
if amount>bal[1]:
IndexError: list index out of range
```

If you have idea, please write.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are nesting the list for the bal inside another list: `[users[str(user.id)]["wallet"]]`. So if `users[str(user.id)]["wallet"]` has the value `[0, 1]`, it will actually be `[[0, 1]]`. There is no index 1, there is only index 0 with a nested list that goes up to the index 1. You can fix this by simply removing the extra brackets: `users[str(user.id)]["wallet"]`.

You could have easily discovered this by `print`ing `bal`. Knowing how to debug is an incredibly useful skill.

Comment: Are you talking about update_bank function? If yes, I tried, there is " 'int' object is not subscriptable " error.

Comment: You are doing `bal[1]`, so you are trying to get index 1 of `bal`. However, bal is already an integer with the value and you cannot index integers.

Comment: thank you very much, it finally works, I should learn how to debug.

Comment: Yeah, a little debugging can go a long way.